# Java multithreaded stateful server - networking design

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to implement a stateful, multi-client server application and have some questions about the networking/threading design. The problem I'm currently facing is how to exchange messages between the communication layer and the logic layer.

The server handles multiple clients, where each of them can be active in multiple "channels", where each channel has multiple stages and may have multiple clients acting in it. Think of it to something similar as a chat program with multiple rooms.

I have already implemented the receiving of messages on the server side. Each client has his own thread that blockingly reads the data and decodes into a message. Now how to proceed? In my oppinion, each channel should also have this own thread to easily maintain its state. I could use a BlockingQueue to exchange the received messages with the channel thread, who's blockingly waiting for new messages on that queue.

But then how to send messages to the clients? The logic in the channel will handle the message, and produce some messages to be sent to one/some/all of the clients. Is it safe to use the channel thread to directly write to the socket? Or should I use another BlockingQueue to transmit the messages to the client handler thread? But how to wake it then, since it's waiting on the socket to read? Or should I use a separate send-thread per client, or even a separate send-socket?

BTW: I know I could use existing libraries for the networking layer, but I want do do it from scratch on plain sockets.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go with multi-threading at all, if the processing is cheap and per-message. I would consider using a reactor instead. The fact that each client and/or channel has state doesn't imply you must use threads.

Comment: @sinelaw I assume you refer to NIO. I read this article http://paultyma.blogspot.com/2008/03/writing-java-multithreaded-servers.html comparing NIO/IO, and so I chose to use one-thread-per-connection (and that's already implemented). But for the channels, another approach could be chosen... The actual question will however be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a send message method on the communication object that wraps the socket.  Synchronize this method so that only one thread can be calling it at once.  Then, it doesn't make any difference how many threads call this method.  Each message will only be sent one at a time.  You also don't have to disturb the thread that's blocking to read.  This send method will be a quick enough operation that you don't have to worry about other threads blocking while a thread sends.

As long as the channel has a reference to the communication objects for each connected client, it can send messages and not worry about it.

If it ever caused problems, you could always modify that send message to enqueue the object to be sent.  Then you could have a specific send thread to block on the queue and write the contents to the socket.  But from my experience, this won't be necessary.

Comment: That's what I meant with "directly write to the socket", which was a  bad forumlation. But it seems strange to me to have one thread for "reading incomming message" and another one for "handling message AND writing responses to multiple clients". But maybe this is just my taste for thread-task decoupling...

Comment: Wouldn't your channel thread be handling messages and writing responses to multiple communication objects?  I don't understand why you would need anything between that thread and your communication objects.  Effectively, that thread would be writing to all of the sockets directly through the communication objects.

Answer (score -1):

What about a event mechanism? When you ready with processing the request and there is a data for client available, then simply send it with an event for the client socket handler thread. as because the transmission from client is ended, you can send reply normally - if i think correctly.